# How to select records from a table as a pair

Tags: sql-server, join

This is really a strange situation. I need to pair up two records in to a single record as item 1 and item 2. can any one help me??
Here is my scenario

```
Table
-----
ItemID  ItemName ItemPrice
--------------------------
1       Item 1    1500
2       Item 2    500
3       Item 3    520
4       Item 4    2500
5       Item 5    1400
```

I need to divide the entire table in to half and pair it up as

```
Result
----------
 ItemID1  ItemName1  ItemPrice1  ItemID2  ItemName2  ItemPrice2
 1        Item 1     1500        2        Item 2     500
 3        Item 3     520         4        Item 4     2500
 5        Item 5     1400        --        --        --
```

I tried FULL JOIN. But it does not pair with item. I am sure we can do it with COLESCE .But, i don't know exactly how to do it with single table. I am trying it. A little help is appreciated.

Comment: You're right, it's a strange situation. It's not what RDBMS is supposed to work with. Any particular reason you need that?

Comment: @Amit , Exactly. I dont need to store in that way. Just to select the records is this way for some specific purpose.

Comment: What I meant in my question is if you could perhaps expend on WHY you need that. It just feels like a mistake, and I suspect your confusing UI with Data, and RDBMS is NOT about UI (P.S. It's not really that difficult to do :-).

Comment: Do you need every pair? Like 1+2, 2+1, 1+3, 3+1, etc? Or just in increasing order?

Comment: Do you need this inside the database for another query, or do you need it only at the presentation layer (user interface) ? If the latter, then you would normally be better off to do it in the presentation layer.

Comment: @SkinnyJ , I don't need every pair. just all items to be paired. The requirement is to have two record details in one row. i don't need duplicates.

Comment: @a4ashiq Who gave you that requirement? Did you talk with the person? What do they want to achieve at all?

Comment: @SQLPolice I dont need it in UI. its for a report file. 
Just that result will do my work.

Comment: @a4ashiq Well, but that's basically the same. Generating the report file = presentation layer.

Comment: My Friends, This is for an old system. I'm trying to do this without changing my source code. I know to accomplish my actual requirement in better way. But this 'strange' query can solve my problem.

Comment: @a4ashiq I understand, that's a good point. Look, often there are questions from people who don't know how a database works. then they want to do complicated things, but they would also be happy with another soluztion. In **your** case now, this makes it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using row_number:

```
select
  max(case when COL = 1 then ItemID end) as ItemID1,
  max(case when COL = 1 then ItemName end) as ItemName1,
  max(case when COL = 1 then ItemPrice end) as ItemPrice1,
  max(case when COL = 0 then ItemID end) as ItemID2,
  max(case when COL = 0 then ItemName end) as ItemName2,
  max(case when COL = 0 then ItemPrice end) as ItemPrice2
from
(
  select
    row_number() over (order by ItemID asc) % 2 as COL,
    (row_number() over (order by ItemID asc) + 1) / 2 as ROWGRP,
    ItemID,
    ItemName,
    ItemPrice
  from
    table1
) X
group by 
  ROWGRP
```

The first row number % 2 assigns the columns, and the second row number + 1 assigns the newly created rows into new rows (1,1,2,2,3,3...) so that the data can be grouped by it.

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b988c5/1)

Comment: You can make a simple self-join, joining even to odd rows. Look at the solution of @Amit.

Comment: @SQLPolice That works only if there is never any gaps in the IDs

Comment: that'S what I commented there ;)  But you could make a CTE, and make the self-join with the CTE.

Comment: @SQLPolice Yes, add row number into a CTE and join it back to itself, but you could also use group by and max :)

Comment: @JamesZ, Thank you so much brother. 
You simply did instead of questioning my boss..!

Comment: @MartinSmith You have 40 free (!) upvotes per day. What's the reason to hold back?

Comment: @MartinSmith Ah, you mean it in the way he is voting far too seldom.

Answer (score 2):

As I wrote in the comments, you should strongly consider whether this is really a RDBMS task of a UI task, but anyway, this will probably work for you:

```
SELECT odd.*, even.*
FROM MyTable odd LEFT JOIN MyTable even
  ON odd.ItemID == even.ItemID - 1
WHERE odd.ItemID % 2 = 1
```

Comment: How you you know that there are no gaps in the ItemIDs? What if you delete the row with ItemID=2 ?

Comment: From data sample and comments, but of course, as we both said this is probably a wrong task anyway